# ANSI C memcpy /w func call. 2 examples. 1 works, 1 does not.

Tags: c, memcpy

Why does Edit  work. and Edit 2 fail to work like edit 1?  Also how to make Edit2 work like Edit?

Edit: Working code from comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char recBuffer[8024];
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(65536);

    strcpy(recBuffer, "Hello\n");

    int bytesRead = 7;
    memcpy(temp , &recBuffer, bytesRead );

    printf("%s\n", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2 Why this fails?:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void Append(char* b, char data, int len)
{
    memcpy(b , &data, len ); 
}

int main() 
{ 
    int bytesRead = 7; 
    char recBuffer[8024]; 
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(65536); 
    strcpy(recBuffer, "Hello\n"); 
    Append(temp, recBuffer, bytesRead);    
    printf("%s\n", temp); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The second version won't compile without warnings/errors.

Comment: Oh wow didnt check warning.. warning C4024: 'Append' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2.  How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your function parameter is `char` not `char*`.  You should make the data parameter `char*` and pass it in directly to `memcpy` instead of passing its address.

Comment: `char const *` would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of Append is a char, not a char*!